# Create an image slideshow with multiple image fields per node

Tags: views, media, javascript

I'd like to create an image slideshow using views slideshow. I see a few ways of doing it, like this one [create-an-easy-jquery-slideshow-in-drupal-7](http://www.bentedder.com/create-an-easy-jquery-slideshow-in-drupal-7/), but they all require a single image per node.

I would like to have a content type that accepts multiple images and still retains similar functionality. So there is a list of thumbnails at the bottom, as a pager, and a single image above that is activated by hovering the thumbnails below.

I'm sure there is a way to do this. possibly with a few more modules? I'd love to know.

EDIT: This is drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drupal 7 for the very basic slideshow you will need views and views slideshow.

You will need to create two imagestyles for the slideshow, a large image, and a small image that will be used for the pager.

next for the view Fields you will need two image fields. One, the first, you will choose the larger imagestyle setting. For the second image filed you will use the smaller imagestyle that will be used for the pager, also on this one you will need to 'exclude from display.'

For the view format choose slideshow. These settings you can use most of the default settings but for the pager type you will be choosing fields and also you will choose the second image type (the pager image.)

For the view contextual filters you'll choose content:nid and choose 'provide default value' with the value being 'content id from url.'

I realise those are very blunt directions but as long as you're looking at your view display you should be able to follow it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Views Slide Show.... See this example I've done here `http://www.cnngo.com/hong-kong/visit/hong-kongs-temporary-june-4-memorial-museum-568132` which is using Views Slideshow (ThumbnailHover) + Simply Scroll Jquery Plugin. See images below...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]